# Take all arguments include after sharp

Tags: bash

I have a function like that :

```
function gcm {
  git commit -m "$*"
}
```

It allows me to do `gcm my commit message` to do a commit. The problem comes when I have to do something like `gcm my commit message #issue-number`. It consider all that comes after # as a comment.

I completely understand that but is there a way to include sharps in the commit message?

I know I can add quotes around the commit message but I also know I will forget many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a `git` issue; you have to quote the `#` in some way to prevent the shell from discarding the `#` onwards as a comment before it even runs `git`:

```
gcm my commit message \#issue-number
```

For this reason, you should simply quote the intended message to prevent any shell interpretation, and write `gcm` to accept exactly one argument, the intended message.

```
gcm () {
  git commit -m "$1"
}

gcm "my commit message #issue-numer"
```

There are many other characters you might include in a commit message that require escaping, so you may as well just quote all of them and pass the message as a single argument. A single pair of quotes is easier to remember than multiple backslashes (or pairs of quotes) throughout the intended message.

You are running `git` from `bash`: learn to use `bash` correctly.

---

You could disable the `interactive_comments` option:

```
$ echo foo #bar
foo
$ shopt -u interactive_comments
$ echo foo #bar
foo #bar
```

but this *only* solves the issue of needing to escape `#`; it does nothing about semi-colons, exclamation points, pathname generation, or other characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: I never said that's a git issue. I know this is about bash. Thanks for your answer.